# CloudFormation template with AWS::ApiGateway::Method failing with "Invalid Resource identifier specified"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm building a CloudFormation template programatically to define API Gateway resources. This is my generated template:

```
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
   "Resources":{
      "MyAPI":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
         "Properties":{
            "Name":"My API",
            "Description":"API description",
            "FailOnWarnings":true
         }
      },
      "APIGatewayDeployment":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
         "Properties":{
            "RestApiId":{
               "Ref":"MyAPI"
            },
            "StageName":"dev"
         }
      },
      "APIGatewayStage":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
         "Properties":{
            "RestApiId":{
               "Ref":"MyAPI"
            },
            "DeploymentId":{
               "Ref":"APIGatewayDeployment"
            },
            "StageName":"dev"
         }
      },
      "APIGatewayResource06bdcf95aafda840b1d04322636de293":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
         "Properties":{
            "RestApiId":{
               "Ref":"MyAPI"
            },
            "ParentId":{
               "Fn::GetAtt":[
                  "MyAPI",
                  "RootResourceId"
               ]
            },
            "PathPart":"users"
         }
      },
      "APIGatewayResource2774b50cf4eb42a0385543f7c5a9b81b":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
         "Properties":{
            "RestApiId":{
               "Ref":"MyAPI"
            },
            "ParentId":{
               "Ref":"APIGatewayResource06bdcf95aafda840b1d04322636de293"
            },
            "PathPart":"{x}"
         }
      },
      "APIGatewayMethod22e900dac82cf1028d805cf4345e6e60":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
         "Properties":{
            "AuthorizationType":"NONE",
            "HttpMethod":"GET",
            "Integration":{
               "Type":"AWS_PROXY",
               "IntegrationHttpMethod":"POST",
               "Uri":"redacted for brevity"
            },
            "ResourceId":{
               "Ref":"APIGatewayResource2774b50cf4eb42a0385543f7c5a9b81b"
            },
            "RestApiId":"MyAPI"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

To my eyes, that looks correct. There's a `AWS::ApiGateway::Resource` for `/users` and a child resource for `/{x}`. When I upload this template it creates the API Gateway endpoints successfully:

[image]

However, it fails to create the `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` resource, citing an invalid resource identifier:

[image]

As we can see in the template the method's `ResourceId` is that of the `AWS::ApiGateway::Resource`:

```
"ResourceId":{
    "Ref":"APIGatewayResource2774b50cf4eb42a0385543f7c5a9b81b"
},
```

And this is the same way the `ResourceId` is specified in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html):

[image]

So what am I doing wrong here?

Side question, the `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment` is also failing with the following message:

> The REST API doesn't contain any methods

which makes sense as my methods are failing to be created, BUT the timestamp of this resource failing to create is BEFORE CloudFormation attempts to create my methods. Do I need to use `DependsOn` here to instruct CloudFormation to create the deployment resource after all the methods are created? I would've thought it was smart enough to do this on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in typical fashion I discovered the issue right after posting and re-reading my question. The issue was:

```
"RestApiId":"MyAPI"
```

in my `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` resource. That needs to be:

```
"RestApiId":{
    "Ref":"MyAPI"
}
```

For my side question, CloudFormation does indeed require you to specify `DependsOn` for `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment` resources to ensure your `AWS::ApiGateway::Method`s are created before the deployment. [It's mentioned on this page of the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-deployment.html).